# Trick a subprocess into thinking it is writing to a terminal

Tags: windows, unix, terminal, subprocess

I observe that some command line programs flush output frequently when running directly in a terminal, and buffer the output otherwise.

I'm running such a program as a subprocess, but I'd like it to flush its output frequently (to give the user better feedback).

I don't have access to the source code of the program.  And I realize that the answer for Windows will be different than for *nix like systems.

Is there a recipe for forcing a subprocess to flush its output frequently for windows and/or for *nix?

Comment: Maybe [`stdbuf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#stdbuf-invocation) from the GNU coreutils could help, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25378/118235).